# Error running nosetests

Tags: python, nose

I recently reinstalled `nose` to run tests on my code.

https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

I used

```
sudo pip install nose
```

and went to my project folder. The response is

```
-bash: nosetests: command not found.
```

So, I once again I uninstalled and tried installing `nose` with MacPorts:

```
sudo port install py27-nose
```

In my project folder, I run

```
nosetests-2.7 filename.py
```

and I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named nose_parameterized)
```

What's the problem?

EDIT: More information. `nose` is installed. I get `Successfully installed nose-1.3.6`.

Comment: looks to me like the installation was unsuccessful.  did the installation itself give you an error?

Comment: No, it doesn't give an error.

Comment: That's probably a path problem. Could you please check if nose is in your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: @Ivan I checked this first (sorry, I should have mentioned it). It's not a path problem, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ok. Can you create a virtualenv without system packages, install nose on it and check if it's working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, the way I've made it work is by specifically downloading [nose-parameterized](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-parameterized/)

```
sudo pip install nose-parameterized
```

Previously `nose` would work in the project's directory, but the trials would always be very quick. For example,

```
Ran 0 tests in 0.002s
```

I'm more confused now than previously. Why would I have to download `nose-parameterized` individually?

Comment: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement nose-parametrized (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for nose-parametrized

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with MacPorts python but I know that Homebrew installs python using a completely different site-packages setup than the OS X provided versions. From the looks of your error messages, it looks like you were mixing a matching the system pip and the ports python which could be the cause of your issue.