# `No module named nose_parameterized` during theano installation

Tags: python, theano, theano-cuda

At the moment I am trying to install theano on my ubuntu 16.04 system with cuda support. The installation process itself went well until I tried to test the installation:

```
python -c "import theano; theano.test()"
```

The last few lines of the output were:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named nose_parameterized)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myUser/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/home/myUser/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/home/myUser/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/home/myUser/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tests/test_rop.py", line 16, in <module>
    from theano.tests import unittest_tools as utt
  File "/home/myUser/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tests/unittest_tools.py", line 7, in <module>
    from nose_parameterized import parameterized
ImportError: No module named nose_parameterized

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 408 tests in 13.085s

FAILED (SKIP=26, errors=80)
```

These were preceded by approximately 20 blocks with what appears to be different tests failing on exactly the same top 3 lines in the stacktrace. The code where the final occurs looks like this (with added line numbers):

```
411. # FIXME: to support module.name names,
412. # do what resolve-name does and keep trying to
413. # import, popping tail of module into addr.call,
414. # until we either get an import or run out of
415. # module parts
416. try:
417.     module = self.importer.importFromPath(
418.     addr.filename, addr.module)
419. finally:
420.     self.config.plugins.afterImport(
421.     addr.filename, addr.module)
```

While searching for a solution I came across:
[Error running nosetests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925801/error-running-nosetests)
I tried the solution proposed there:
`sudo pip install nose-parameterized`
However this had no effect. Does anyone know what else could be causing this error?

edit: so I reinstalled theano to make the problem more reproducible. I installed theano using the instructions found [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_ubuntu.html#install-ubuntu), so I used:

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-dev python-pip python-nose g++ libopenblas-dev git  
sudo pip install Theano
```

Then I used:

```
nosetests theano
```

The last few lines of the output of this are almost the same as earlier:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named nose_parameterized)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myUser/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/home/myUser/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/home/myUser/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/home/myUser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tests/test_rop.py", line 16, in <module>
    from theano.tests import unittest_tools as utt
  File "/home/myUser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tests/unittest_tools.py", line 7, in <module>
    from nose_parameterized import parameterized
ImportError: No module named nose_parameterized

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 457 tests in 160.608s

FAILED (SKIP=24, errors=95)
```

edit 2: I thought it might be a python-version issue. When I try:

```
python -V
```

I get:

```
Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)
```

And the following folders exist:
`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose_parameterized`
So, that shouldn't be a problem as far as I can see. However when I try:

```
python2.7 -c "import nose_parameterized"
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named nose_parameterized
```

Comment: Do you use a virtualenv? If so, might wanna install nose-parameterized in there. Is there a requirements.txt somewhere?

Comment: As far as I know I don't use a virtualenv, how would I check? Searching through home also didn't turn up any `requirements.txt` related to either nose, nose-parameterized or theano

Comment: If you don't know if you're using virtualenv; you're not using virtualenv. You should probably read up on it though. It allows you to create "isolated" python working enviroments with its own modules. Other than that, I haven't a clue, never used Theano.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, then I'll leave this open hoping someone else has experience with this error

Comment: how did you install theano?

Comment: I added this information in an edit, this should make the error reproducible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem, anaconda was looking in its own folder. So to solve, I did:
`conda install nose-parameterized`

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

`pip install nose-parameterized`